# Is every factorial divisible by its sum of digits?

Tags: puzzle

Denote by $\Sigma_d(t)$ the sum of digits in the decimal representation of the number $t$.

Prove / disprove:

$$\forall n\in \mathbb N:\ \ \Sigma_d (n!) | n!$$

Comment: $\Sigma_d (n!) = O(n \ln (n))$ grows faster than $n$, so there's no clear reason to think it's asymptotically true. Have you looked for counterexamples?

Comment: Table[Mod[n!, Plus @@ IntegerDigits[n!]], {n, 1, 500}]

Comment: How about $0$ ?

Comment: what about sum of binary digits? (following the usual observation that there's nothing special about 10)

Comment: @Mitch my comment above is base independent, so it's not likely to hold for any base.

Comment: @Mitch, I wrote a program to generate the first counterexamples in arbitrary bases. For bases 2 through 30, the first counterexamples are 10, 43, 86, 87, 188, 156, 291, 364, 432, 410, 7, 510, 4, 4, 4, 813, 4, 1079, 4, 1900, 6, 10, 6, 2330, 2147, 5, 3463, 2401 and 7 respectively.

Comment: @G.H.Faust: Add it to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)!!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's not true.  The first counterexample is for $ n = 432 $.  The sum of the digits in $ 432! $ is 3897, which you can see [using Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20digits%20in%20432%20factorial).  But the prime factorisation of 3897  is $ 3^2 \times 433 $, so $ 432! $ cannot be divisible by its sum of digits.

The list of counterexamples is sequence [A066419](http://oeis.org/A066419) in the OEIS.

Comment: The fact that the first counterexample has $n + 1$ as its only large prime factor is somewhat remarkable.  It's like the hole-in-one of counterexamples.

Comment: One of the classics "patterns that eventually fail".

Comment: Curious that $432, 532, 632$ are each counterexamples (though not $732$)

Comment: @HashirOmer: I wouldn't say that. n! is divisible by 9 for n >= 6, therefore the sum of digits is divisible by 9. You would expect that the sum of digits is eventually 9 times a prime, and since the sum of digits grows faster than n, you would expect that eventually that prime is greater than n. Very predictable that it would happen.